# Numpy assign certain bit of a 32 bit number to a number?

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy is it possible to assign certain bit of a 32 bit number to be equal to a value? For example can I set bit range 13:16 to be 0x00010000?

```
weights_table = np.zeros((output_channels, 1, 1, 4)).astype(np.int32)
for channel in range(output_channels):
    weights_table[:, :, :, 31:16] = hex(0x00010000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use combination `np.bitwise_or` and `np.bitwise_and` to do it:

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]).astype(np.int32)

v = np.bitwise_or(v,0x00010000) # set required bits to 1
v = np.bitwise_and(v,0x0001FFFF) # set required bits to 0
```

See [Numpy: Binary operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.bitwise.html) for details.